# Adding right and left glyphicons next to indicators bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap carousel on my website, instead of using the usual circle indicators I am using thumbnail images of each picture. I am planning on doing this dynamically later so at the moment have just added sample images.

I want my right and left glyphicons to line up next to the first and last thumbnail however I can't see to get it right. I attempted to put it in the  but that wasn't successful.

Previous

```
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="single-indicator">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
      <img src="images/robin-thumb.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
       <img src="images/robin-thumb.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
       <img src="images/robin-thumb.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </li>

          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
       </a>


  </ol>


  </div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
top: 320px;
 left: 270px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 15%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.carousel-control.left {
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
}
.carousel-control.right {
  left: auto;
  right: 115px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
}
```

Comment: Will be better if you can make an example on Bootply

Comment: Also, that HTML is invalid...lists can only contain list items as children...not anchor links. I suspect your structure is at fault.